# Visual Studio Team Services TFS VS 2015 - Checked in pending changes not uploading to cloud

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am new to VS 2015 as pertains to using TFS as my source control.

I have created a Visual Studio Team Services account and project successfully.

I automatically creates a folder BuildProcessTemplates and that shows up when I view my work space in VS 2015 so I know connectivity exists between VS 2015 and VSTS/TFS.

However when I add my solution to the new project although the bindings are find if I go to FILE->Source Control->Advanced->Workspace when I actually go to: Check In Pending Changes from the Source Control Explorer nothing is ever actually uploaded to the cloud.

The pending changes tab shows all the new files that should be uploaded to actually give me source control but that is as far as it goes. I have even added a comment for the Check In.

This has been driving me crazy for 6 hours now. I cannot understand how there can be no error message nor can I understand how I cannot find this scenario on Google. I just keep ending up at MSDN pages that are as useless as a bicycle to a fish.

Someone please help... :D

Answer (score 1):

I ended up opening Fiddler to see what the traffic was. Then I set the local folder with my solution to NOT be read only.

Then I undid all pending changes so that I could once again add the solution to source control.

Then all of a sudden the Team Explorer tab's, "Pending Changes" UI displayed a "Check In" button. I clicked it and Fiddler showed the files uploading.

That was brutally painful. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Since the issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.